# Syren 10 A motor driver stopped working

Tags: motor, motor-controller

While I was measuring current going in the motor terminals , sparking occurred and the power supply also stopped working including the motor driver, as soon as I connected multimeter across motor terminals of the driver.
Earlier it was working fine , after measuring current this happened. The current measured during that time (for micro second) came out to be 17 A which  happens to be in safe range for peak current of driver i.e 20 A.( I did switch to ampere mode in multimeter before measuring)

Datasheet for Motor Driver :-

https://www.dimensionengineering.com/datasheets/SyRen10-20.pdf

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. So what is your question? Note that you have supplied no schematic, links to datasheets for the motor, driver or multimeter so it is not clear how you think we could help. There is an "edit" link under your question ... Also, please clarify: did you switch your multimeter to "amps" and then connected across the motor terminals thereby shorting out the supply?

Comment: @Transistor Yes , I did switch to amps before measuring .

Comment: Are you aware that current measurements are taken **in series** with the load and not in parallel with the load? If you connected in parallel with the load then you have short-circuited the driver with the low shunt resistance of the multimeter amps range.

Comment: @Transistor Yes , I did connect it in parallel. Is there any way I could retrieve the driver ?

Comment: You say in your comment that you connected in parallel BUT you say in your question "connected across the motor terminals" so you have probably blown a fuse at minimum, or the driver is now toast, so buy a replacement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffDVWP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Incorrect and correct current measurement techniques.*

Connecting an ammeter as shown in Figure 1a may result in destruction of the driver or the ammeter or both. High quality multimeters are fused on both low and high ampere ranges. If you are replacing the fuse then be sure to use the correct version specified by the meter manufacturer.

The driver datasheet says it is short-circuit proof. If so it should have survived but maybe not. There is no schematic on the datasheet and I can't see any big switching transistors or chips that look like they could handle 20 A so maybe they're mounted on the back of the board. As a result I can't comment on the possibility of repair. You might have to write this off as an educational cost!

Comment: Like "educational cost" ie "learning experience" ...